# EventListener doesn't work Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a problem conncering listeners. I am building an JS HTML CSS webpage with drags and drops. Sometimes i need a Dialogwindow to ask if they are sure to do what they want to do... I did this by implementing listener to the buttons they click. And if they click they fire a new event.notify(). Long text here is my code:
one example:

onKochtopfDropped gets fired when i drop something there. This is working.

```
function onKochtopfDropped(event) { 
    if (quest.isStillFresh(event.data.alt)) {
            view.addEventListener("amountSubmitted", function(evt){
            addToKochtopf(event.data, evt.data);
            view.removeEventListener("amountSubmitted");
        });
        view.showModal("Insert the amount to cook with:", false, true);


     }
    else
        {
            view.showModal("One does not simply cook with outdated food...", false);
        }
    }
```

In the showModal there is a submit Button and when i press "submit":

```
function onAmountSubmit (){
    var amount = document.getElementById("amountInput").value;
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modalAmount.style.display = "none";
    that.notifyAll("amountSubmitted", amount); //line 75 
    }
```

Sooo everytime I try to submit something i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at context.EventPublisher.notifyAll (events.js:36)
at HTMLButtonElement.onYes (fridgeAppView.js:75)
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Your code and your error are different. Can you create codepen?

Comment: what is codepen? I basically get the same error